# A Finite Field of Order $125$ has a Subfield of order $25$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

How to prove that every finite field of order $125$ has a subfield of order $25$. In general what is the strategy to attack such kind of problems?

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91087/subfields-of-finite-fields

Comment: You'll never prove it, it’s not true.

Comment: Consider objects of the form $x^5$, where $x$ ranges over the big field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider a field $F$ with $q$ elements, $q$ being a power of some prime. Suppose $L$ is a field containing $F$, with $[L\colon F]=m$. Since $L$ is an $F$-vector space of dimension $m$, $|L|=q^m$. Thus $[\mathbb F_{125}\colon\mathbb F_5]=3$. Now do you see why there’s no field strictly between these two fields?

Comment: Thank you. I understand your argument. I didnt in the least feel this could be a false statement.

Comment: You don't need to consider $\Bbb F_5$, simply $[\Bbb F_{125}:\Bbb F_{25}]$ would have to be $3/2$, which is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

So if there is a subfield G of size 25, you can remove the zero element and it becomes a group under multiplication. Specifically, it is a subgroup of F-{0}, but F-{0}=124, and 24 doesn't divide 124. All subgroup sizes must divide the size of the group they come from, therefore you can never have a subfield of size 25.