# Does the field with 27 elements contain a subfield with 9 elements?

Tags: finite-fields, extension-field

> Does the field with $27$ elements contain a subfield with $9$ elements?

I fail to make the extension of $\mathbb{F}_3$ with degree $3$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/91087/11619) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/233996/11619)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a theorem that if $K\subseteq L\subseteq M$ are algebraic field extensions, then
$$
[L:K]\cdot [M:L] = [M:K]
$$
In your case, you have a $K$ and an $M$, and you're wondering whether there can be an $L$. What would the numbers in the above equality be? Is that possible?

Comment: thank you, I get that!

Answer (score 11):

If $L/K$ is a field extension, then $L$ is a vector space over $K$.
If $L$ and $K$ are finite, $L$ must be finite-dimensional over $K$.
Let $K$ have $q$ elements and $L$ have dimension $n$ as a vector
space. Then $L$ has $q^n$ elements. Is there an integer $n$ with $27=9^n$?