# If p is a prime positive integer, find all subfields of GF(p)

Tags: prime-numbers, finite-fields

If p is a prime positive integer, find all subfields of GF(p)

This question just seems too vague.

Comment: This has been answered in more generality at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91087/subfields-of-finite-fields

Comment: $GF(p)$ has not proper subfields.

Comment: see well known book by Van Der Waerden "Algebra"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any subfield necessarily contains the multiplicative identity, $1$. Because the characteristic of $\mbox{GF}(p)$ is $p$, we know that $1$ generates an additive subgroup of order $p$, which can only be $\mbox{GF}(p)$ itself. Hence any subfield containing $1$ also contains $\mbox{GF}(p)$. It follows that there are no proper subfields.

Comment: Or simply note that $G(p)$ as an additive group has no non-trivial subgroups.