# Subfields of $F_2[x] / (x^3 + x + 1)$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

What are the subfields of $F_2[x] / (x^3 + x + 1)$? I know $F_2$ is a subfield, and so is itself, but I'm not sure if there are any more.

Thanks!

Comment: What is $F_2$? a field with 2 elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subfileds of  any finite field of order $p^n$ are exactly of order $p^r$ where $r$ divides $n$.You may see it here:[Subfields of finite fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91087/subfields-of-finite-fields). Now can you conclude?