# There is a ring homomorphism of F into E when$|E|$ is not a power of $|F|$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, ring-homomorphism

Let F and E be ﬁnite ﬁelds of the same characteristic. In Milne's notes exercise. It says it is not true that There is a ring homomorphism of F into E iff $|E|$ is a power of $|F|$. But I cannot find such an example. So to see it clearly. I am searching for such an example. Could someone give one? Thanks.

Comment: $\Bbb F_4$ is a subfield of $\Bbb F_8$, isn't it?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sorry I haven't heard about that. May I ask why is that true？

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen $\Bbb F_4$ is **not** a subfield of $\Bbb F_8$.

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen just posed that as a question for OP to ponder.  I would add $\Bbb{F}_2$ and $\Bbb{F}_{16}$ to the list as well.  What inclusions are there and how do the cardinalities relate?  Another hint:  this is sometimes stated as a field of of $p^d$ elements embeds in a field with $p^{d'}$ elements iff $d|d'$

Comment: Related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91087/subfields-of-finite-fields

Comment: @sharding4 I have just read it. Note that my question is why we also have a homomorphism when the order in **NOT** a power of another.

Comment: There's always the trivial map I guess.

Comment: Please check the claim. A ring homomorphism from one field to another is always injective. So the domain is isomorphic to a subfield of the range. I haven't checked but I would be somewhat surprised if ring homomorphisms don't map the unit to the unit for Milne.